# Angular Route Matcher Childrens Not Loading

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm trying to replicate a Twitter like URL (i.e. `@username`). As far as I know I can achieve it using `matcher`instead of using `path`. Everything works so far, but sadly I cann't access my child routes with using `matcher`. Instead of loading the `component`I defined, it loads the parent component.

My code:
app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomeModule),
  },
  {
    matcher: (url: UrlSegment[], group: UrlSegmentGroup, route: Route) => {
      if (!url || url.length === 0) {
        return null;
      }

      const pattern = new RegExp(/^@[\w]+$/gm);

      if (!pattern.test(url[0].path)) {
        return null;
      }

      return {
        consumed: url,
        posParams: {
          username: new UrlSegment(url[0].path.substr(1), {}),
        },
      };
    },
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./profile/profile.module').then((m) => m.ProfileModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'post',
    loadChildren: () => import('./post/post.module').then((m) => m.PostModule),
  },
];
```

This route is accessible through `/@johnsmith`. Now I define another route called `info` with component `ProfileInfoComponent`

profile-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    children: [
           {
               path: 'info',
               component: ProfileInfoComponent,
  },
    ],
  },
];
```

other variation

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProfileComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'info',
    component: ProfileInfoComponent,
  },
];
```

but going to `/@johnsmith/info` loads up the parent component (`ProfileComponent`) instead of `ProfileInfoComponent`. Any reason why?

Comment: May be I missed something but `/@johnsmith/info` __should__ load `ProfileComponent` and __then__ load `ProfileInfoComponent` because first is the parent of second.

Comment: @Dimanoid yea probably when I use it inside `children`. Actually, I don't really wanna use that in there. It was only to demonstrate that both variations aren't working. The actual `selector` is also not showing up, only the selector of `ProfileComponent`.

Comment: Well confs looks good, its hard to say what's wrong. I can suggest to turn routing tracing on and see what is happening https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#enableTracing

Comment: @Dimanoid so as far as I can see, there is no really a thing I can notice by tracing the route. I guess it's because the routes are defined in other modules. `components` are `null` in every route, but still showing the right `component`. I can post the full trace here.

Comment: I faced this same problem some time ago. My solution worked because I had only one matcher. So I placed the module to load the at last then handle 404 errors from there. Everything that doesn't match I redirect to the 404 page.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working somehow by changing `consumed: url` to this `consumed: url.length === 1 ? url : url.slice(0, 1),`

Comment: this saved my day. I think it's horribly documented on official page...

Comment: @Tomas glad to see that it helped you. You're absolutely right....

Comment: I used your advice to on a route for `http://localhost:4200/family/efa7bdd6-92ef-41a7-a4fb-1b28a728482d/profile` and `http://localhost:4200/resident/efa7bdd6-92ef-41a7-a4fb-1b28a728482d/profile`. Using the slice(0,1) worked. I don't understand why

Comment: @Mattijs just check my next answer. Sorry for the late response!

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see that it helped some of you. It's been a while and I actually moved to React / NextJS now, but I guess I can kinda explain what's happening.

Consider this code:

```js
const urlSegments = ['@johnsmith', 'info'];
const slicedUrl = urlSegments.slice(0, 1);
console.log('Segments:', urlSegments, 'Sliced URL Segment:', slicedUrl);
```

Our router matcher simply checks for the first match (`/@johnsmith`) and ignores every following segment. Afterwards, it loads our `ProfileModule` & the assigned `ProfileModuleRouter` trough lazy-loading.

Somehow, it cannot send the next URL segments to our following module router, thats why we match `@johnsmith` & load our `ProfileModule`, which loads `ProfileRoutingModule` and passes only `info` to the `ProfileRoutingModule` router, containing the param `username`.

It could be different now, but that's what I can remember. :)

Edit:

I don't know if this approach would work for nested child-child, so there is this solution (based on my text above):

```js
      return {
        consumed: url.length > 1 ? url[0] : url,
        posParams: {
          username: new UrlSegment(url[0].path.substr(1), {}),
        }
      }
```

It should just match the route and pass every other segments to the next router in our lazy-loaded module.